# Semisimple module without composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> I can't find a semisimple module that doesn't have a composition series.

I know every semisimple ring has a composition series as subrings, but i am not sure about modules.

Edit: Am right about the rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module has a composition series if and only if it is both Noetherian and Artinian. So you are looking for a semisimple module which is not Noetherian. An example would be $\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus\Bbb{Z}_2\cdots$ as a $\Bbb{Z}$-module.

Answer (score 1):

Take any vector space over a field $k$ with a countably infinite basis, such as the space of polynomials $k[x]$.